FFMPEG не использует CPU на полную

Есть два сервера, один с 4 ядрами, другой с 8.
Если на втором, с 4 ядрами, при работе ffmpeg, процессор загружен  на полную, почему на сервере с 8 ядрами, ffmpeg не берет доступные еще 30-40% потенциала CPU дабы быстрее обработать видео?

Возможно, что сервер с восемью ядрами - это четыре пары ядер связанных через hypertreading. Эти пары ядер делят некоторые железные компоненты ядра, обычно связанные с вычислениями. То есть, на интенсивных вычислениях эти восемь ядер работают немногим лучше чем четыре обычных ядра. Проверить можно запустив 4/8 однопоточных вычислительных теста. Если общая производительность отличается на в два раза, вы пользователь такого процессора.

Возможно, что система охлаждения не способна охладить процессор с восемью работающими ядрами. Тогда система стартует бодро, но быстро нагревается и сбрасывает рабочие частоты ядер (троттлинг). Проверяется контролем за температурой и тем как температура связана с производительностью. И снова желателен тест из 4/8 однопоточных вычислителей.

@StanislavVolodarskiy тут похоже vps. Врятли тротлинг

Как запускаете ffmpeg?

Слово "сервер" - это ни о чём. Что? Где? Как? Сервера, как я понимаю, должны быть ещё и заняты чем-то. И ради ffmpeg не обязаны всё бросать и "бежать исполнять, взяв под козырёк". Все эти замеры - ситуативны и ни о чём. Сервер может быть занять в момент замера чем угодно и по-взрослому.
